# Check if a BigDecimal is a multiple of another BigDecimal in Java 1.4

Tags: java, bigdecimal, java1.4

I needed to check if a BigDecimal instance is a multiple of another BigDecimal instance. Since I am restricted to Java 1.4, I couldn't make use of `BigDecimal.remainder(...)`.

I came up with the following code:

```java
/**
 * Returns <code>true</code> if <code>multiple</code> is a multiple of <code>base</code>.
 *
 * @param multiple
 * @param base
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isMultipleOf(final BigDecimal multiple, final BigDecimal base)
{
    if (multiple.compareTo(base) == 0)
        return true;

    try
    {
        multiple.divide(base, 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY);
        return true;
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code assumes that rounding is unnecessary only if the quotient of `multiple` divided by `base` is an integer. Is this assumption correct?

***Edit***
Incorporated the hint by Lando to explicitly set the scale of the quotient to `0`. Otherwise the following call would have wrongly returned `true`:

```
isMultipleOf(new BigDecimal("10.25"), new BigDecimal("5"));
```

***Edit***
Wrote a JUnit test and found out I have to take care of the special case where both `multiple` and `base` are `0`. So I added a test for equality to the code above.

Comment: May be look at Java 1.6 or so source, that gives you what you want exactly right?

Comment: Its worth noting that Java 6 is soon to be End Of Free Support so if you do upgrade, I suggest going straight to Java 7. ;)

Comment: Nambari, that's what I did. However, as it is with good design, high level functionality is implemented via specificly parameterized calls to multi-purpose low-level functionality (mostly private methods here). I would be ending up copying the whole class. Take a look: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The decision if and when to upgrade is not mine :( The code must be executable on our customers application server (an SAP NetWeaver WebAS 7.0) which only supports Java 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc says...

> Throws: **ArithmeticException** - if divisor==0, or roundingMode==ROUND_UNNECESSARY and this.scale() is insufficient to represent the result of the division exactly.

So the **assumption seems correct** that an `ArithmeticException` will occur if the `scale()` is not sufficient; i.e. remainder is non-zero.

Comment: `System.out.println(isMultipleOf(new BigDecimal("125"), new BigDecimal("10")));` returns `false`. The scale is different for 1.25 the scale is 2 and for 125 scale is 0.

Answer (score 2):

you should use this instead:

multiple.divide(base, 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY);

Because if you don't pass the zero it will apply the scale of the dividend (unless you are completely sure that the scale of that will always be zero in which case why are you not using a BigInteger instead?)

> ArithmeticException - val==0, or roundingMode==ROUND_UNNECESSARY and
>   **this.scale()** is insufficient to represent the result of the division
>   exactly

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int%29)

Comment: Good hint! The scale of the dividend can go up to 2, maybe more. Thanks!